# AngularJS: Service Listening to another Service

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory/service listening to another factory/service. Problem is, the factoring listen only "hears" the first factory once.... The first factory is called every so many seconds; however, factory 2 does not hear the changes.

***How do I get a factory to listen for changes on another factory that is consistently returning a value?***

**Factory 1 :**

```
app.factory('pollServerFactory', function($timeout, $http) {
    resource.query = function() {
        $http({.....get data......}).success(function(data){
            resource.pollResults = data;
        }
    };
    resource.startPoll = function() {
        resource.query();
        $timeout(resource.startPoll, 3000);
    };
  return resource;
});
```

**Factory 2:**

```
app.factory('parseInfoFactory', function(pollServerFactory){
    var logData = pollServerFactory;
    console.log(logData);
});
```

**Controller Initializing Factory 1 loop**

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, pollServerFactory) {
    pollServerFactory.startPoll();
});
```

Comment: What does parseInfoFactory does exactly ? It is not even been injected to the controller... can you provide more information about this ?

Heads up, if parseInfoFactory is not beeing resolved anywhere, it's constructor will not run, and the logData will never be logged.

Comment: I simplified the code... but I do have a controller that displays the values returned from Factory 1... The problem is that the pollServerFactory returns a very large object (statistical data for various people). I am trying to separate the parsing into separate factories in order to make the code more readable and manageable.

Comment: if you define array or object and pass reference of those but never break that reference by reassigning them... makes it simple to pass references back and forth. Alternative is use $rootScope to emit events

Comment: If your separating the parsing process in several factories, the pollServerFactory should require them, not the other way around. Then when the poll query is finished the other factories can be called for the parsing. Then, finally, the controllers should point to the parser factories, not the pollServerFactory.